# ¿Como establecer numberOfRowsInSection a partir de una peticion alamofire?

Tags: swift, alamofire

Nesecito sacar el valor de mi petición para setear el valor de las filas

```
func getProjects(_ role:Int, _ idUser:Int, done:@escaping (_ response:JSON)-> Void){
        let parameters:Parameters = ["role":role,"idUser":idUser]


 Alamofire.request("http://localhost:8000/value",method:.post,parameters:parameters).responseJSON{
            response in
            let json = JSON(response.value)
            done(json)
        }

}
```

ocupo sacar el valor del json para setearlo en la funcion ya intente con viewWillAppear pero por ser asincrono no se puede

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return json.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

primero debes hacer un parseo de ese json, deberias incluir en tu pregunta el contenido del json para estar mas en contexto.....

y en tu viewcontroller donde llamas la funcion getProjects

```
        var rows = 0 

        getProjects(role:Int, _ idUser:Int){(response) in 
            self.rows = response
            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return rows
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementando la respuesta que te está dando sergio, ya que donde obtendrías el valor es al sacarlo en el CompletionHandler que tienes, y lo seteas a una variable universal `var jsonValue = [String: Any] ()'`, eso lo seteas cuando obtengas el valor, claro la variable dependara si estas recibiendo un JsonObject. te pongo el siguiente ejemplo.

```
var jsonValue = [String : Any]() //suponiendo que es un json object lo que vas a recibir {'key': 'value'}
//ahora cuando mandes a llamar tu método
getProjects(1, CompletionHandler: {(response)
   self.jsonValue = response as! [String : Any]//como explique en el caso que estes recibiendo un jsonObject
   //haces el relogueo de la table
   self.table.reload()//nombre de la variable de tu tableView
})

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return jsonValue.count
}
```